# How do I remove the download option in the HTML5 audio tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I am using the HTML5 audio tag on a website I'm maintaining.  I noticed that the audio tag has a download icon embedded in it.  How do I remove that option? I want the audio to be read (playback) only.  Is there a way to do this without JavaScript or jQuery? I don't know either one yet.

Comment: If you're hoping to employ that as copy protection: it's not that simple. In order to read (playback) the audio, the browser must already have **downloaded** the file (perhaps to a temporary file on disk). Saving it to a more permanent file from there is a trivial step…

Comment: What browser? Are you using a media library that supplies its own UI (i.e., **not** the controls supplied by the HTML `<audio>` element)? Can you supply a screenshot in the question? (Or, if it won't let you because you're a new user, can you link to a screenshot?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this might it help you. It is not the best way but I think it will solve your problem.

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    overflow:hidden;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    width: calc(100% + 30px); /* Adjust as needed */
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This did exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 5):

To remove the download option from the UI add controlsList="nodownload" attribute

```
        <audio
           controls
           controlsList="nodownload">

        </audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing on the [`audio`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-audio-element) element interface that controls only the download button. There is the [`controls`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-media-controls) attribute, which is a Boolean attribute, just shows or hides all of the controls on the audio UI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function that I have used to get the desired results. Hope it helps...

```
function disable_audio_download() {
?>
<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('.wp-block-audio audio').forEach(function(audio) {
        audio.setAttribute('controlsList', 'nodownload');
    });
</script>
<?php
```

}
add_action('wp_footer', 'disable_audio_download');

Answer (score 0):

Just add this `controlsList="nodownload"` right above the `controls` like this:

```
<audio
      id="audio-element"
      controlsList="nodownload"
      controls
      className="w-full rounded-lg p-2 bg-gray-200 border border-gray-400"
    >
      <source
        src={`http://localhost:3000/api/audiobook/stream/${audioBook?._id}`}
        type="audio/mpeg"
      />
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```